# When sending packets using the unetstack simulator, the packets are split and transmitted

Tags: unetstack

My name is Junny.
On Ubuntu, I encountered a problem while testing sending packets using UnetStack Simulator.
Using UnetStack Simulator, two nodes were created and a TCP Portal was created on each node.
The application I created connects to the TCP Portal as a client and sends packets. As a result of capturing the packet using Wireshark, I can confirm that it is transmitted as a single packet in my application. However, one packet (258 bytes) received from the TCP Portal is separated into three (128 byte units) and delivered to another application connected to the opposite node. In other applications, the packet must be received in one chunk (258 bytes). However, it is currently being received in three pieces. I wonder how I can receive packets without being split. thank you

I changed the settings of the Groovy file that runs the unetstack simulator.

Comment: Are you sure you mean TCP portal? TCP portals provide a data stream over a TCP connection, and do not have a concept of "packets". https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_portals.html